# Help me find a way to get mold off my bathtub mat

Tags: bathroom

How do I get the mold off my bathtub mat? I have used vinager and bleach please help! Any ideas I don't want my kids sitting on mold.

Comment: Time for a new mat?

Comment: If bleach doesn't do it, then I agree it's time for a new mat. Though most mold is harmless.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in direct sunlight for a day or two. (Also works great for removing tomato stains from plastic.)

Answer (score 0):

Try making a paste out of baking soda and bleach and smearing it on the mat and letting it sit there that will hold the bleach in contact with the surface of the mat long enough for the bleach to work better. If this doesn't work it may be time just to replace the mat.